# React Native Test Error - Unable to find node on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

I have very limited knowledge of testing React and React Native apps. So I just started  to setup some tests in my React Native app. I am using expo so I have installed jest, jest expo, react-test-renderer. I wanted to check with a very simple test which I'm thinking probably is not a simple test may be because of the navigation but anyways I cannot get past this error below. I'm posting my code for the app, test and the error I see.

In package.json

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"
    ],
```

App Component

```
 import React from 'react';     
 import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
 import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
 import MemberHomeScreen from './src/screens/MemberHomeScreen';
 import SignUpScreen from './src/screens/SignUpScreen';
 import { setNavigator } from './src/navigationRef';
 import SignInScreen from './src/screens/SignInScreen';
 import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
 import MemberDetailsScreen from './src/screens/MemberDetailsScreen';
        
        const appNavigator = createStackNavigator(
          {
            Home: HomeScreen, 
            MemberHome: MemberHomeScreen,
            SignUp: SignUpScreen,
            SignIn: SignInScreen,
            MemberDetails: MemberDetailsScreen
          },
          {
            initialRouteName: 'Home',
            defaultNavigationOptions: {
              title: '',
              headerLeft: () => false,
              headerTitleAlign: 'center'
            }
          }
        );
        
        const App = createAppContainer(appNavigator);
        export default () => {
          return <App ref={navigator => {setNavigator(navigator) }} />
        }
```

NavigationRef.js

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let navigator;
export const setNavigator = (nav) => {
  navigator = nav;
}

export const navigate = (routeName, params) => {
  navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params
    })
  )
}
```

Test

```
import React from "react";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import App from "../../App";

describe("App Component", () => {
    it('renders correctly', () => {
      const tree = renderer.create(<App />)
    });
});
```

[image]

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Appreciate any guidance.
Thank you!

Comment: So guess this does have something to do with navigation or something else in the App component because the similar test works for other components.

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into the same error after updating my dependencies.

Tests are running fine after downgrading `react-test-renderer` from major version `17` back to the lastest `16`. Seems fine even when `react` & `react-dom` are at version 17, although there will be an incorrect peer dependency warning.

Comment: Worked for me. The latest 16 is 16.14.0, so I downgraded with "yarn upgrade react-test-renderer@16.14.0".
Here is also an entry on GitHub. You could subscribe to it to get infos when the bug is fixed: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9023

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you! I upgraded back to 16 and test run!

Answer (score 5):

Just ran into this problem after upgrading my React-Native version to 64.2
Upgrading [react-test-renderer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-test-renderer) to the highest public version, which is **17.0.2** at the moment has helped.

Comment: This also works for upgrading to Expo SDK 43. `react-test-renderer` is not automatically updated.

Answer (score 0):

This has caught me out a few times as well, so one thing to check is that you’re using the latest syntax. For me, I was using the React Native Testing Library:
https://testing-library.com/docs/react-native-testing-library/example-intro/

I also got the `Unable to find node on an unmounted component` error when writing multiple tests for a single component. It turns out I wasn’t calling the render function in the correct place. I tend to use `describe` and `it` and therefore was calling the render function outside of the `it` function when in fact it should be written like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import { ExampleComponent } from './ExampleComponent';

const props = {
  title: 'Example Title',
  body: 'Example body text',
};

describe('Example Component', () => {
  it('should match snapshot', async () => {
    render(<ExampleComponent {...props} />);
    expect(screen.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('should render title', async () => {
    render(<ExampleComponent {...props} />);
    const exampleComponentTitle = await screen.findByTestId('example-component-title');
    expect(exampleComponentTitle).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should render body', async () => {
    render(<ExampleComponent {...props} />);
    const exampleComponentBody = await screen.findByTestId('example-component-body');
    expect(exampleComponentBody).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `test.only(...)` instead of `test` or `it` to run only that test.
2. If it works that way it might mean other tests interfere with this one. In my case it was the common redux store creating the error. I just created mock store for every test.